# Alternative dependencies error when switch from dune 1.1 to dune 2.0

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I switched my dune project version from `(lang dune 1.1)` to `(lang dune 2.0)` which produced an error for the handling of alternate dependencies.

I had the foolowing in my dune file which worked with **dune 1.1**:

```
(select vpl_domain.ml from
  (vpl -> domains/numeric/vpl_domain.ok.ml)
  (!vpl -> domains/numeric/vpl_domain.ko.ml))
```

But produces with **dune 2.0** the error

> The format for files in this select branch must be
> vpl_domain.{name}.ml

I've tried to remove the path before the filename like this:

```
(select vpl_domain.ml from
  (vpl -> vpl_domain.ok.ml)
  (!vpl -> vpl_domain.ko.ml)))
```

which seems to make dune happy about the format but gives the error

> No rule found for vpl_domain.ko.ml

Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug of dune or did they voluntarily make breaking changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out in the [documentation](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#rule) that:

> Dune officially only supports user rules with targets in the current directory